# Java proxy https implementation

Tags: java, sockets, https, proxy

I try to make my own proxy server and already implemented the http support for my proxy server. The proxy server works fine.
Now I want to have https as well (only with sockets). I looked up what I have to do at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817.
In my function I try to establish a TLS tunnel.
With my approach I only get a method not allowed as response. I also check some source in the internet, but didn't find anything which can help me with my problem.

Here is my function.

```
private Socket openTLSTunnel(String host) throws IOException {
    String raw_request = "CONNECT " + host + ":80 HTTP/1.1\n"
            + "Host: " + host + ":80"
            + "\r\n\r\n";

    // Make a connection to the website.
    Socket tunnel = new Socket();
    int timeout = 10000;
    var server = new InetSocketAddress(host, 80);
    tunnel.connect(server, timeout);


    // Write the request to server.
    OutputStream out = tunnel.getOutputStream();
    byte[] msg = raw_request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    out.write(msg);
    out.flush();

    // TODO send error to client.
    // Get the response from server.
    InputStream in = tunnel.getInputStream();
    byte reply[] = new byte[200];
    int replyLen = 0;
    int newlinesSeen = 0;
    boolean headerDone = false;

    while (newlinesSeen < 2) {
      int i = in.read();
      if (i < 0) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected EOF from proxy");
      }
      if (i == '\n') {
        headerDone = true;
        ++newlinesSeen;
      }
      else if (i != '\r') {
        newlinesSeen = 0;
        if (!headerDone && replyLen < reply.length) {
          reply[replyLen++] = (byte) i;
        }
      }
    }
    String replyStr = new String(reply, 0, replyLen, "ASCII7");

    // Check if connection established.
    if(!replyStr.toLowerCase().contains("200 connection established")) {
      System.out.println("No TLS connection established!");
      throw new AccessDeniedException(replyStr);
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Connection established!");
    }

    return tunnel;
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https on port 80, are you sure? Wouldn't it be 443?

Comment: If I have understood it correctly, I have to establish first with an http request for a secure tunnel and with that I will connect via port 443. What is in my source link which I have linked.

Comment: @XaniXxable: The CONNECT request should give the target server and port, which would be ususally port 443 when reaching a HTTPS server. But you should not match on the exact phrase "200 Connection established" since the phrase can be different. All what matters is the HTTP status code of 200. For this you better properly parse the response to extract the status code from the right place instead of just `contains` somewhere in the response.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Ok yeah I tried the HTTPS port of course and after trying to read from the stream I get -1 and so my exception will throw. 
Yeah I should definitely  change condition for the response code, thx. But it will still not work since I get a *405 Method Not Allowed* response.

Comment: @XaniXxable: *"405 Method Not Allowed"* - This simply means that this proxy does not allow CONNECT and thus will not proxy HTTPS. That's true for many of the "free" proxies found on the internet. *